# Absurd Firestore Collections and Security Rules inheritance

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I have Firestore Collections structure like this

```
../cards/{cardId}/data/{dataId}
```

to `safely read data` I need this call on Firestore Security Rules

```
get(/databases/$(database)/documents/cards/$(cardId)).data
```

then compare of card fields. It's basically 2 reads everytime I do this.

yet if I change my structure by making it all parent like this (but also has to make some similar fields on both model).

```
../cards/{cardId}
../data/{dataId}
```

It does need only 1 read. But I need 2 writes each time because of changes on both similar fields. Write call does less than reads which makes it cheaper, but this is annoying to code. And this makes Firestore inheritance useless.

I mean, can Firestore just have ability to read parent fields too with no cost? At least for Security Rules. Firestore basically is making index for each field right? So, can it just also `understand` the meaning of inheritance which is make the child `know/have` parent fields too?. Or this is just the limitation of NoSQL? It's really annoying every time I runs into this.

Answer (score 0):

> can Firestore just have ability to read parent fields too with no cost?

Stack Overflow isn't the right place to ask a question like this.  But I'll speak confidently and say that, no, Firestore can't have any free writes (outside of the free monthly allowance), else it will not be a service that can sustain itself from the money it receives in revenue.

If you have feedback to send to the Firebase team, [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  But I suspect that asking to relax the billing requirements of the system is not going to be a request they will entertain.

> can it just also understand the meaning of inheritance which is make the child know/have parent fields too?.

What you're describing is not really "inheritance".  It's simply nesting.  Collections can be nested under documents within other collections.  The relationship between those documents is only in the path prefix that they have in common.  Other than that, each document stands fully on its own without any ties to any other documents in the system.

> Or this is just the limitation of NoSQL?

It has nothing really to do with NoSQL.  The relationship between collections and subcollections is just a way that you can organize data in the system.  You choose the method of organization that best suits the queries (and security requirements, when using security rules) for your app.  Whether that organization is nested or not, it's up to you.

But there is no way to organize your data to get free reads.  Each document read always costs 1 read, no matter how it's organized.